# Error in compiling angular 11 (upgraded from angular 9) application

Tags: angular, ivy

I have an angular 9 application which is now upgraded to angular 11.
Now on compiling angular application I am getting below error.

```
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at ComponentDecoratorHandler.analyze (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\annotations\src\component.js:210:79)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.analyzeTrait (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:346:40)
    at analyze (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:298:58)
    at _loop_1 (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:320:21)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.TraitCompiler.analyzeClass (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\transform\src\compilation.js:326:35)
    at NgccTraitCompiler.analyzeFile (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\analysis\ngcc_trait_compiler.js:48:26)
    at DecorationAnalyzer.analyzeProgram (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\analysis\decoration_analyzer.js:140:39)
    at Transformer.analyzeProgram (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:130:57)
    at Transformer.transform (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\packages\transformer.js:76:27)
    at C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\create_compile_function.js:49:42
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:195:27)
    at C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:293:57)
    at step (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)
    at C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RJhaveri\Documents\Ronak\SourceCode\Development\SNSConversionAutomation\sns-conversion\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:321:20)
```

Please suggest how to fix the issue.

Comment: have you upgraded angular materials as well? Angular recommends stepwise upgrade from 9,10,11. Did you use the angular upgrade cli?

Comment: No, i have upgraded app from 9 to 11. I believe that is the reason application is not compiling. Is there any way out?

Comment: Did you use the angular cli for upgrading?

Comment: Yes upgrade is done using angular cli

Answer (score 0):

I think problem was due to application was upgraded directly from version 9 to version 11.

Finally, i had to again move to angular 9 version and then convert it to 10. And from version 10 to version 11. Now application is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the points

1. Please follow [guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-11.0) in detail setp by step [link](https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-11.0)
   but in your case
2. Your old application have aot errors and for deprecation errors come so you just have to fix them.
3. If still facing any issue then, in your project **angular.json**

   "aot":"true"

   to

   "aot": "false"